# iOS: UIImage is not assignable (FBSDKGraphRequest)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimage, fbsdk

I'm building a function for retrieving profile picture of a user. I'm using facebook's FBSDKGraphRequest but as soon as I'm trying to use the data I retrieved to assign it into a picture, I get an error I do not understand: `Variable is not assignable (missing _block type specifier)`

My function is below:

```
- (UIImage *)getProfilePicture: (NSString *)ID
{

    FBSDKGraphRequest *requestFriends = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name"}];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

    //[connection addRequest:requestFriends completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)

    UIImage* profilePic;


    NSString* requestPath = @"me/?fields=name,location,gender,birthday,relationship_status,picture,email,id";
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture"}];
    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError* error)
    {
        NSDictionary* data = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSDictionary* picture = [data objectForKey:@"picture"];
        NSDictionary* pictureData = [picture objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString* pictureURL = [pictureData objectForKey:@"url"];
        profilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureURL]]];
    }];

    return profilePic;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you to add `__block` before `profilePic` declaration.

`__block UIImage* profilePic;`

Yet, it won’t solve your issue.

The point is that your 
`-(UIImage *)getProfilePicture: (NSString *)ID` 
method is synchronous, while `FBSDKGraphRequest` call (with completion block) is asynchronous.

What I may suggest you to do is to add an UIImage callback to your method, or use the delegate pattern to return the image when the completion block is called by Facebook SDK.

Another solution, but not really practical: making the call fully synchronous, your method will wait until the `FBSDKGraphRequest` is completed and then return a UIImage, but it will block a thread the method is running on (probably, the main one).

Comment: Adding `__block` fixed the error, however as you stated, the function doesn't work. How do I add the UIImage callback to my method that you suggested?

Comment: e.g. define ```typedef void (^ImageCompletionHandler)(UIImage *img);``` and pass ```ImageCompletionHandler``` as a parameter to the `getProfilePicture` method. You can face the same issue 1-level up then, but I think assigning image to ```UIImageView``` or whatever you need will do just fine.